# Ошибка выделения динамической памяти

Tags: c++

Есть решение, состоящее из двух проектов. Первый это статическая библиотека

.h

```
#pragma once
extern "C"
{
    char* _stdcall copystr(char*, char*);
    char* _stdcall sumstr(char*, char*);
    void _stdcall outstr(char*);
    void _stdcall outint(int);
    int _stdcall squareroot(int);
    char* _stdcall substr(char* s, char* ss);
}
```

.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "library.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)
extern "C"
{
    char*  _stdcall copystr(char* str1, char* str2)
    {
        if (!str1 || !str2)
        {
            std::cout << "ERROR: Null string pointer in copystr function!!!" << std::endl;
            system("pause");
            ExitProcess(0);
        }
        else
            return strcpy(str1, str2);
    }
    char* _stdcall sumstr(char* str1, char* str2)
    {
        char* buf = new char[255];
        if (!str1 || !str2)
        {
            std::cout << "ERROR: Null string in sumstr function!!!" << std::endl;
            system("pause");
            ExitProcess(0);
        }
        strcpy(buf, str2);
        strcat(buf, str1);

        return  buf;

    }
    void _stdcall outstr(char* s)
    {
        if (s != nullptr)
            std::cout << s << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "Empty line!";
    }
    void _stdcall outint(int i)
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
    int _stdcall squareroot(int i)
    {
        return (int)std::pow(i, 2);
    }
}
```

Второй-проект ассемблера. Пытаюсь запустить данный код:

```
.586
.model flat, stdcall
includelib kernel32.lib
includelib libucrt.lib
includelib "D:/учёба/2 курс/ЯП/Курсовой/Debug/Lib.lib"

ExitProcess PROTO : DWORD
squareroot PROTO : DWORD
copystr PROTO : DWORD, : DWORD
sumstr PROTO : DWORD, : DWORD
outstr PROTO : DWORD
outint PROTO : SDWORD 
.stack 4096
.const
    overflow db 'ERROR: VARIABLE OVERFLOW', 0 
    null_division db 'ERROR: DIVISION BY ZERO', 0
    _Lit1 BYTE "as", 0
.data
.code

main PROC
    push offset _Lit1
    push offset _Lit1
    call sumstr
    push eax
    call outstr


    jmp EXIT
    EXIT_DIV_ON_NULL:
    push offset null_division
    call outstr
    push - 1
    call ExitProcess

    EXIT_OVERFLOW:
    push offset overflow
    call outstr
    push - 2
    call ExitProcess

    EXIT:

    push 0
    call ExitProcess

main ENDP
end main
```

При вызове функции sumstr на строке char* buf = new char[255]; выскакивает следующая ошибка в файле malloc_base.cpp:

Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x770CE066 (ntdll.dll) в ASM.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0x00000044

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что не проинициализирован рантайм.
Не используйте фичи языка, которым нужен рантайм, например.

Comment: Можно подробнее?
И это единственный выход?